# ENOENT error in Next.js 14.0.4: Missing BUILD_ID file

Tags: node.js, next.js

I am encountering an ENOENT error in my Next.js 14.0.4 project related to the missing BUILD_ID file. Here are the details of my project setup:

- Node.js version: 21.5.0
- Next.js version: 14.0.4

> client@0.1.0 start
> next start

▲ Next.js 14.0.4

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:*.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '*\.next\BUILD_ID'
}

-Deleted the .next directory and rebuilt the project.
-Checked for updates in project dependencies using npm install.
-Reviewed and ensured the correctness of my code related to starting the Next.js application.

Answer (score 1):

`BUILD_ID` is an auto-created file by `next build` to save unique key for the build. It's located in `/.next`.

The error you're encountering simply means this file or `.next` doesn't exist.

To solve:

run `npm run build` then `npm run start`.

**Note:** Don't remove/modify anything in `.next` folder unless you have a reason. As a beginner you might not have a reason to remove it at all.